# How to access array element inside another array

Tags: php, arrays

Using PHP,
I want to echo only address value , how i will get.

Using an API

```
print_r(coinpayments_api_call('get_deposit_address'));
```

I get:

```
Array ( [error] => ok [result] => Array ( [address] => 34JHMyDLriZizkV7nZZo63FbHzJetWhTqd ) )
```

How i print only address value  ,that is=34JHMyDLriZizkV7nZZo63FbHzJetWhTqd  ?

Comment: `$array['result']['address']`

Comment: you should study basics, see it here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp

Answer (score 6):

You can access the value of an associative array by using the key between square brackets. If you want a value on a lower level, you can keep adding square brackets.

```
$array = coinpayments_api_call('get_deposit_address');
echo $array['result']['address'];
```